# Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long,

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting the followoing error:

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in
>   /home/users/2/catfood.jp-cybercat/web/academy/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 112

Which points to the line:

```
$datemonth = $wp_locale->get_month( $datefunc( 'm', $i ) );
```

What changes are required to the above line to resolve this?

Here is the whole codes

```
function date_i18n( $dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp = false, $gmt = false ) {
global $wp_locale;
$i = $unixtimestamp;

if ( false === $i ) {
    if ( ! $gmt )
        $i = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    else
        $i = time();
    // we should not let date() interfere with our
    // specially computed timestamp
    $gmt = true;
}

/*
 * Store original value for language with untypical grammars.
 * See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9396
 */
$req_format = $dateformatstring;

$datefunc = $gmt? 'gmdate' : 'date';

if ( ( !empty( $wp_locale->month ) ) && ( !empty( $wp_locale->weekday ) ) ) {
    $datemonth = $wp_locale->get_month( $datefunc( 'm', $i ) );
    $datemonth_abbrev = $wp_locale->get_month_abbrev( $datemonth );
    $dateweekday = $wp_locale->get_weekday( $datefunc( 'w', $i ) );
    $dateweekday_abbrev = $wp_locale->get_weekday_abbrev( $dateweekday );
    $datemeridiem = $wp_locale->get_meridiem( $datefunc( 'a', $i ) );
    $datemeridiem_capital = $wp_locale->get_meridiem( $datefunc( 'A', $i ) );
    $dateformatstring = ' '.$dateformatstring;
    $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])D/", "\\1" . backslashit( $dateweekday_abbrev ), $dateformatstring );
    $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])F/", "\\1" . backslashit( $datemonth ), $dateformatstring );
    $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])l/", "\\1" . backslashit( $dateweekday ), $dateformatstring );
    $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])M/", "\\1" . backslashit( $datemonth_abbrev ), $dateformatstring );
    $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])a/", "\\1" . backslashit( $datemeridiem ), $dateformatstring );
    $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])A/", "\\1" . backslashit( $datemeridiem_capital ), $dateformatstring );

    $dateformatstring = substr( $dateformatstring, 1, strlen( $dateformatstring ) -1 );
}
$timezone_formats = array( 'P', 'I', 'O', 'T', 'Z', 'e' );
$timezone_formats_re = implode( '|', $timezone_formats );
if ( preg_match( "/$timezone_formats_re/", $dateformatstring ) ) {
    $timezone_string = get_option( 'timezone_string' );
    if ( $timezone_string ) {
        $timezone_object = timezone_open( $timezone_string );
        $date_object = date_create( null, $timezone_object );
        foreach( $timezone_formats as $timezone_format ) {
            if ( false !== strpos( $dateformatstring, $timezone_format ) ) {
                $formatted = date_format( $date_object, $timezone_format );
                $dateformatstring = ' '.$dateformatstring;
                $dateformatstring = preg_replace( "/([^\\\])$timezone_format/", "\\1" . backslashit( $formatted ), $dateformatstring );
                $dateformatstring = substr( $dateformatstring, 1, strlen( $dateformatstring ) -1 );
            }
        }
    }
}
$j = @$datefunc( $dateformatstring, $i );

/**
 * Filter the date formatted based on the locale.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @param string $j          Formatted date string.
 * @param string $req_format Format to display the date.
 * @param int    $i          Unix timestamp.
 * @param bool   $gmt        Whether to convert to GMT for time. Default false.
 */
$j = apply_filters( 'date_i18n', $j, $req_format, $i, $gmt );
return $j;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the get_month() and datefunc() function definitions/

Comment: What is `$i` and what is `$datefunc`? Maybe run `strtotime` on `$i`...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added the whole codes of the function please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

`$datefunc` is an alias obviously to php's date method. If that's the case, you are trying to get the month from passing a single integer `1-12`. When you can't do that, you need to pass a timestamp to PHP's date method then depending on the attributes you pass as options will return you the following data. Then you are passing it to wordpress locale get_month method that returns the name of the month. You need to refactor your code, so that $i isn't a for loop variable. If you are just trying to get Jan - Dec just do

```
$i = 1;
$monthArray = [];

do {

    // Just push the months to an array and pass it to the view
    array_push($monthArray, $wp_locale->get_month($i);
    $i++;

} while($i < 13);
```

Then do what you need to with it. If you are getting a record back from the DB, you need to access the appropriate value in the returned model. Otherwise you're passing an array object. If you are accessing a model you should do)

```
// Access the property that you intended to retrieve the month on.
$datemonth = $wp_locale->get_month( $datefunc( 'm', $i['published_at'] ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am a beginner and I don't know what you are talking about. I added the whole codes of the function. Please take a look at it.

Comment: @ギャングスタキャット秋月 where are you using this function at in your code base? This is a core wordpress method, you shouldn't go changing these files unless you need to extended out additional functionality on top of what is already there. You are incorrectly using this method somewhere else in your wordpress project. I need to see the entire stack trace in order to give you a definitive of what is actually happening.

Comment: Oh I see. I changed codes a lot. I uploaded the plugin again and it doesn't show any problems. Thank you for helping me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a plugin called "paid membership pro" and this plugin was written in English and I translated into Japanese. There were lots of codes like this:

```
<?php printf(__('課金 #%s ( %s )', 'pmpro'), $pmpro_invoice->code, date_i18n(get_option('date_format'), $pmpro_invoice->timestamp));?>
```

I tried to change these codes as follows:

timestamp), $pmpro_invoice->code );?>

I guess that's why it caused the problem. What do you think?

Now I downloaded the plugin again and there is no problem.

Thank you for helping me.